# How to avoid Maven Integration for Eclipse JDK Warning

Tags: java, eclipse

For reasons I don't understand, everytime I import a project into my Eclipse I've got this warning :

[image]

Here you can find my eclipse.ini file, it seems that the path is good so I can't really find out how to avoid this warning.

[image]

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-vm` entry must be **before** the `-vmargs` line in the eclipse.ini.

This is because all lines after `-vmargs` is treated as a VM arguments which is not what you want.